# How to pass parameters to a view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a series of buttons which when clicked display a popup menu positioned just below the button. I want to pass the position of button to the view. How can I do that?

```
ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    events: {
        'click': 'showMenu'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    render: function() {
    return $(this.el).html(this.model.get('name'));
    },
    showMenu: function() {
        var itemColl = new ItemColl();
        new MenuView({collection: itemColl}); // how to pass the position of menu here?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You just need to pass the extra parameter when you construct the MenuView. No need to add the `initialize` function.

```
new MenuView({
  collection: itemColl,
  position: this.getPosition()
})
```

And then, in `MenuView`, you can use `this.options.position`.

**UPDATE:** As [@mu is too short states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803138/backbone-js-how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-view#comment28706113_7807449), since 1.1.0, [Backbone Views no longer automatically attach options passed to the constructor as this.options, but you can do it yourself if you prefer.](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog)

So in your `initialize` method, you can save the `options` passed as `this.options`:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.options = options;
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
},
```

or use some finer ways as [described by @Brave Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20930054/468793).

Comment: This no longer works as of 1.1.0: ["Backbone Views no longer automatically attach options passed to the constructor as `this.options`, but you can do it yourself if you prefer."](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog).

Comment: This works perfectly, just add the parameter in your view initialize method: initialize: function (options) {
        alert(options.position);
    }

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache No, it doesn't work. This answer uses `this.options.position`, not `options.position`. Views used to attach the `initialize` arguments to `this.options` but that stopped happening in 1.1.0.

Answer (score 46):

Add an options argument to `initialize`:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    // Deal with default options and then look at options.pos
    // ...
},
```

And then pass in some options when you create your view:

```
var v = new ItemView({ pos: whatever_it_is});
```

For more information: http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor

Comment: this is more elegant/simple for most of the situations.

Comment: @CullenSUN: Thanks. I prefer the explicitness of this approach, the magical "action at a distance" of using `this.options` gives me maintenance and debugging nightmares.

Comment: I saw the Backbone link first but your example clarified it for me. Thanks

Comment: This has been deprecated, and you can no longer use `this.options`

Comment: @Trip: Huh? `initialize: function(options) { ... }` is just fine, the change is that Backbone no longer automatically sets `this.options` for you: ["Backbone Views no longer automatically attach options passed to the constructor as `this.options`, but you can do it yourself if you prefer."](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog).

Comment: @muistooshort so `initialize: function(options) { this.options = options }` would be fine?

Comment: @alapeno: You could do that but I think unpacking `options` into properties is still a better idea. If you use `this.options` all over the place then it is very difficult to know what your view's interface really is and that just leads to maintenance problems.

Comment: You can use the [backbone.viewOptions plugin](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/backbone.viewOptions) to white-list initialization options and automatically attach them directly to your view.

Answer (score 12):

As of backbone 1.1.0, the `options` argument is [no longer attached](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) automatically to the view (see [issue 2458](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2458) for discussion). You now need to attach the options of each view manually:

```
MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        _.extend(this, _.pick(options, "position", ...));
    }
});

new MenuView({
    collection: itemColl,
    position: this.getPosition(),
    ...
});
```

Alternatively you can use [this mini plugin](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/backbone.viewOptions) to auto-attach white-listed options, like so:

```
MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({
    options : ["position", ...] // options.position will be copied to this.position
});
```

Answer (score -1):

pass from other location

```
 new MenuView({
   collection: itemColl,
   position: this.getPosition()
})
```

Add an options argument to initialize in view you are getting that passed variable,

```
initialize: function(options) {
   // Deal with default options and then look at options.pos
   // ...
},
```

to get the value 
use -

```
   var v = new ItemView({ pos: this.options.positions});
```

Comment: write improved answers not collective.

Comment: This is improved answer !

Answer (score -2):

Use **this.options** to retrieve argumentr in view

```
 // Place holder
 <div class="contentName"></div>

 var showNameView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:'.contentName',
        initialize: function(){
            // Get name value by this.options.name
            this.render(this.options.name);
        },
        render: function(name){
            $('.contentName').html(name);
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Passing name as argument to view
        var myName1 = new showNameView({name: 'Nishant'});
    });
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cpn3g/1771/