# Backbone 1.1.0 Views - Reading Options

Tags: backbone.js

The changelog to Backbone.js 1.1.0 states:

> Backbone Views no longer automatically attach options passed to the constructor as this.options, but you can do it yourself if you prefer.

My question is how can I do it now?  previously, I had `this.var = this.options.var` regularly in my views.

Comment: possible duplicate of [backbone.js: how to pass parameters to a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803138/backbone-js-how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-view)

Comment: I disagree.  My question asked how to read the options within the view post-1.1.0 not how to pass the parameters to the view pre-1.1.0.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you want to access to passed options - just save them:

```
initialize: function (options) {
  this.options = options || {};
}
```

If you use ES6:

```
initialize (options = {}) {
  this.options = options;
}
```

If you want to save passed options for all `Backbone.View`'s you can override `constructor` like **ncksllvn** [suggested below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19431552/1104483).

Comment: any reason not to include a typeof options !== 'undefined' check?

Comment: @mikeyUX, In any case `this.options` will be `undefined` :)

Comment: A couple other things to keep in mind if you take this route: 1) Views that don't have an initialize() defined need to add one like above, and 2) any direct calls to initialize (e.g. not using the `new` keyword) needs to pass the options as an argument.

Comment: @Kyle I don't think you can pass `options` as an argument. Wouldn't it have to be within an `attributes` hash? And then if you did that, why not just name everything attributes instead of options? So far the above solution has not worked for me because of this..

Comment: would it make sense to do this.options = arguments || {} and leave an empty argument?

Answer (score 34):

My team was already invested in using `this.options` in certain instances, and I didn't want to go through and modify the `initialize` method for every subclass of Backbone.View. As soon as Backbone is loaded, we override the Backbone.View `constructor` similiar to McGarnagle's answer, but with seamless integration:

```
// Compatibility override - Backbone 1.1 got rid of the 'options' binding
// automatically to views in the constructor - we need to keep that.
Backbone.View = (function(View) {
   return View.extend({
        constructor: function(options) {
            this.options = options || {};
            View.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
})(Backbone.View);
```

Comment: var view = new Backbone.View(); In that case view.options will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth taking a look a [backbone.viewOptions](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/backbone.viewOptions) for a minimalist implementation of view options that supports white listing and default values.