# Getting a TypeError: this.options is undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to learn BackboneJS and this is the error that I am getting.

I am coding in coffeescript and this is the generated JS I have no idea why this is happening as I think that I am doing it correctly.

```
(function() {
  var AppRouter, MenuItemDetails, app;

  MenuItemDetails = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
      var markup;
      markup = "<div>" + this.options.category + "</div>";
      this.$el.html(markup);
      return this;
    }
  });

  AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      "": "list",
      "menu-items/new": "itemForm",
      "menu-items/:item": "itemDetails"
    },
    list: function() {
      return $('#app').html('List Screen');
    },
    itemDetails: function(item) {
      var view;
      view = new MenuItemDetails({
        name: item,
        category: 'Entree',
        imagepath: 'no-image.jpg'
      });
      return $('#app').html(view.render().el);
    },
    itemForm: function() {
      return $('#app').html("New item form");
    }
  });

  app = new AppRouter();

  Backbone.history.start();

}).call(this);

/*
//@ sourceMappingURL=app.map
*/
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is this similar to this question / answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325323/backbone-1-1-0-views-reading-options  Basically, this.options may no longer be available by default.

Comment: Thank you so much! You sent me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this :

```
  MenuItemDetails = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
      this.options = options;
    },
    render: function() {
      var markup;
      markup = "<div>" + this.options.category + "</div>";
      this.$el.html(markup);
      return this;
    }
  });
```

Comment: This is the right answer, although it could use a bit more explanation. The explanation is basically this: `options` is no longer set on `this` in the constructor, but you can still do it yourself, because it is passed to the `initialize` method as the sole argument.

Answer (score -2):

You're using the `this` keyword incorrectly.

```
MenuItemDetails = Backbone.View.extend({
render: function() {
  var markup;
  markup = "<div>" + this.options.category + "</div>"; // Error
  this.$el.html(markup);
  return this;
 }
});
```

The this is pointing to a scope that doesn't contain the property options. Yous should instead do something like this

```
 var self = this;
 MenuItemDetails = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        var markup;
        markup = "<div>" + self.options.category + "</div>"; // Error
        this.$el.html(markup);
       return this;
   }
 });
```

Comment: I tried this :
initialize: function(options) {
    return this.options = options || {};
  },
And it worked.

Comment: While your point is true in plain JavaScript, that is not true when using Backbone's extend. Backbone will copy the functions you define and pass to `extend` to the object's prototype so `this` will be correctly set to an instance of the object when they are invoked.